# Insert looped variable to one table column

Tags: asp-classic

I have Checkbox form and I am trying to save my loops values into a variable.

This is how I am looping:

```
For i = 1 to Request.Form("packages").count
Set packnamn = ObjConn.Execute ("Select * from services_package where id='"&
Request.Form("packages")(i) &"'")

panamn = packnamn("name") & "-"
Response.write panamn
Next
```

This will output

```
Greece-English-Spanish-
```

Now im trying to save the whole output in my MySQL. But i'm only getting the last value of the loop (Spanish-), This is my insert code.

```
Dim sql1
sql1= "insert into tariff_plan(package)"
sql1=sql1 & " VALUES "
sql1=sql1 & "('" & panamn &"')"

on error resume next
ObjConn.Execute sql1,recaffected
if err<>0 then
    Response.Write(err.description)
else
    response.write "Saved"
End if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the values to a variable where you are doing the response.write and do the insert after the loop.

```
panamn = ""
For i = 1 to Request.Form("packages").count
  Set packnamn = ObjConn.Execute ("Select * from services_package where id='"&
  Request.Form("packages")(i) &"'")

  panamn = panamn & packnamn("name") & "-"

Next
Response.write panamn
```

`'Do the insert here`